# Incorrect Number of Arguments for PROCEDURE when selecting data from MySQL database

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, stored-procedures

I am trying to convert a c# method that contains a SQL query into a call to a stored procedure. The method works correctly with a query application side, but I am getting the error `Incorrect Number of Arguments for PROCEDURE dat.checkUsernameSetup; expected 1, got 0`. Im not sure why this is happening.

Here is the code that before it was converted:

```
public bool CheckUsername()
{
    try
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * From `tbl_user` WHERE `username` = @uname;", Conn);
        DataTable table = new DataTable();
        MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
        /*cmd.CommandType.Equals(CommandType.StoredProcedure);*/
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", usernameField.Text);
        adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
        adapter.Fill(table);

        if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
        {

            return true;
        }
        else
        {

            return false;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Here is the code after:

```
    public bool CheckUsername()
    {
        try
        {
            using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("checkUsernameSignUp", Conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType.Equals(CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@uname", usernameField.Text);
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(table);

                if (table.Rows.Count > 0)
                {

                    return true;
                }
                else
                {

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Here is my stored procedure:

```
drop procedure if exists checkUsernameSignUp; 
delimiter //
create procedure checkUsernameSignUp(IN `uname` varchar(100))
    BEGIN
        SELECT username From `tbl_user` WHERE `username` = uname;
        COMMIT;
    END//
delimiter ;
```

How might I fix this error?

**Note:** Conn is referenced to my connection string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mistake is here:

```
cmd.CommandType.Equals(CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

It should be:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

The reason is that [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.equals?view=net-5.0) is a method which returns a `bool` to indicate if theya re equals. Your code is effectively comparing the current value of `cmd.CommandType` to `CommandType.StoredProcedure` and discarding the result.

Comment: Thats weird, In some methods the way I have done it works, but this method doesn't seem to work and works the way you said

Comment: @johnny In the other methods were you using a standard SQL query or were you using a stored procedure? The default value for `cmd.CommandType` (`CommandType.Text`) works fine for standard SQL queries because it's intended for text queries.

Comment: Here is an example of one that works  Conn.Open();
          try
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("GetPlayerUsernames", Conn);
                cmd.CommandType.Equals(CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    playerComboBx.Items.Add(reader.GetString("username"));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            Conn.Close();

Comment: Ah, that looks to be because you're not actually passing any parameters.

Comment: Given your response, Im assuming this one works because its a public void not a public bool

Comment: Oh, Ive done ones where I pass parameters too

Comment: try
            {
                DataTable table = new DataTable();
                MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("AdminDeleteGame", Conn);
                cmd.CommandType.Equals(CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@game", gameComboBx.Text);
                adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
                adapter.Fill(table);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }